# boot2docker on windows missing apt-get / package manager

Tags: windows, docker, apt-get, boot2docker

I'm in boot2docker.  I'm not entirely sure I understand it completely, but it seems to be needed for a project I'm on.

I've ssh'd in, and I tried to do a make on our project, but I got

```
make: not found
```

Then I tried a:

```
apt-get install make
```

And got

```
apt-get: not found
```

Tried googling, but couldn't find anything about that, or any package manager.

Any suggestions on how to install anything in boot2docker?

EDIT:
When I asked this I misunderstood how boot2docker and docker worked hand in hand.  There is actually a package manager (tce-load) that allows install of packages, but really, it shouldn't be used and anything involving a project using docker should be using a docker container within boot2docker that has the build tools inside of that.  Although I did find tce-load useful installing nano, since I'm not a fan of vi and that's occationaly useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems boot2docker uses Tiny Linux which has its own package manager called "tce-load".  There's a list of packages for it here:

http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/tcz_2x.html

There's everything that's needed to make or whatever located there.

Comment: For example, I needed a text editor and found nano on the list above:  it installed simply with `tce-load -wi nano`.

Comment: this is so God damn frustrating, all these flavors of Linux.

Comment: so what command did you ultimately run to get apt-get package installed?

Comment: There is no apt-get and you don't need it. In tiny linux it's alternative is "tce-load", use that instead of apt-get, it's a small distro so not as many packages are available.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be installing anything on the boot2docker vm as that gets deleted and reset often. You should install any tools inside a docker container running on the boot2docker vm.

Comment: That's a valid answer, in my example someone has created a Makefiles to build docker images and that requires `make`

Answer (score -5):

Only linux can run docker so when running on osx or windows you must use boot2docker. boot2docker is just running a linux vm that has docker installed. Once you are using boot2docker you use docker like you would normally.

The boot2docker vm is not where you should be installing things, what you should be doing is running a container that has the programs you need installed. This can be accomplished by finding a useful image from the docker registry or by making your own docker image.