# How to install VirtualBox Guest Addition on TinyCore

Tags: linux, virtualbox, tinyos

When I run "sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" just like on Ubuntu or CentOS, TinyCore throws errors and failed, and the /var/log/vboxadd-install.log shows that:

```
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error:
unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. 
Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

I have used tce tools installed some packets such as gcc, make, linux-kernel-sources-env.tcz, linux-3.16.2_api_headers.tcz, and then the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run can get the KERN_DIR, but no KERN_INC at this time.

If anybody has done this before could you please give me some points? I really don't know which packages should be installed in TinyCore to make VBoxAdditions work. My VBox and TinyCore is up to date. Thanks.

Comment: This is my best lead so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621810/boot2docker-on-windows-missing-apt-get-package-manager

Comment: I found [this article on how to do it](http://www.markn.org/blog/2015/01/tiny-core-6-vbox-file-sharing.html#more)... I have not verified it yet...

Answer (score 0):

Found a repo for this issue, but have yet to verify:

https://github.com/MSumulong/vmware-tools-on-tiny-core-linux

Prior to that, I attempted to follow this tutorial, but it is incomplete:

https://www.gilesorr.com/blog/tcl641-guest-additions.html

Prior to that, attempted to build the kernel headers (`/lib/modules/5.15.10-tinycore`) with no luck.

Copying the Guest Additions to home folder and running `sudo VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` returns "Kernel headers not found for target kernel 5.15.10-tinycore. Please install them and execute `/sbin/rcvboxadd setup`"

Answer (score -4):

Basically you have to install the package linux-headers-${kernel_version}

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

This solved my problem on Debian linux.
To check the version of your kernel, you should run the command:

```
# uname -a
# Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 # SMP Debian
```

Comment: This answer would be a lot nicer if it was actually applicable for Tiny Core which is not derived from Debian...

The correct way to install headers is through `tce`, and the package is `linux-kernel-sources-env.tcz`.